# Gorm Has Changed Field?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have Save function like this. I want to lookup one of the columns has changed or not. I know there is Changed func for Update&Updates but I wonder if there is something for Save function ?

`r.Connection.MysqlDB().Save(user).Error`